# OTP Code View, Auto Layout not working - Swift

Tags: swift, autolayout, one-time-password

I'm working on an OTP View and have tried multiple ways to move the UIView but the autolayouts simply don't change. Can someone help me to set the view just below the text[image: (see picture)]?

This is the code that I'm using.

```
       func setPinVIew() {
        let pinView = VKPinCodeView()
        pinView.length = 6
         pinView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
         view.addSubview(pinView)
         pinView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 40).isActive = true
         pinView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -40).isActive = true
         pinView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        
         pinView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
         pinView.onSettingStyle = { UnderlineStyle() }
         pinView.becomeFirstResponder()
        
        pinView.onComplete = { code, pinView in
            self.buttonStatus()
            
            if code.count == 6 {
                print("code: \(code)")
                self.pinCode = code
                self.buttonStatus()
            }
       
            
//            { pinView.isError = true }
            
               }
        

    }
```

Comment: "help me to set the view just below the text" what "text" are you referring to?

Comment: sorry! Thought I had added the picture :). The picture is up now. As you can see the UIView can be seen behind the text.

Comment: There is nothing in the constraints to set the location of the pin view relative to the text label.  You've constrained the pin view to always be in the center of its parent, but you don't show any code that would position the label.

Comment: Which is is your text view & which one is uiview? Do you want to move pinView?

Comment: Yeah I want to move the pinView down.